# Summarise all confidence intervals

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(gmodels)
library(dplyr)

df<- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,c=11:15)

df %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,max))
```

At the moment I have a df which is producing a summary of the mean, sd, min, and max.

```
df %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,max, function(x) ci(x,confidence=0.95)[2]))
```

I am wanting do something similar and add lower ci (and eventually upper) ci using dplyr. However this is the error I get: Error: `function(x) ci(x, confidence = 0.95)[2]` must be a function name (quoted or unquoted) or an unquoted call, not `function`.

Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a back-trace.

```
sapply(df, function(x) ci(x,confidence=0.95)[2])
```

I know I can get the lower ci with a `sapply` but want to do this in `dplyr`.

Comment: You can use the `.` notation i.e. `df %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(.), sd(.), min(.), max(.), ci(., confidence = 0.05)[2]))
`